# Hibernate filter children

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables one being the parent of the other. The child table has start date and end date columns, which determine its validity.
The following filter setup works for loading only the valid children:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@FilterDef(name = "dateFilter", parameters = @ParamDef( name = "targetDate", type = "string" ))
@Filter(name = "dateFilter", condition = "(:targetDate between to_char(startDate, 'yyyyMMdd') and to_char(endDate, 'yyyyMMdd')")
public class Child {}
```

What I want is to load all the parents and only the valid children starting with the parent entity definition. The following code loads all the children, not only the valid ones:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Collection<Child> childCollection = new HashSet<Child>();
}
```

How do I specify a filter for the parent entity class that acts on the children?

Comment: How you write that derived query method?? Could you please mention that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@FilterDef(name = "dateFilter", parameters = @ParamDef( name = "targetDate", type = "string" ))
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @Filter(name = "dateFilter", condition = "(:targetDate between to_char(startDate, 'yyyyMMdd') and to_char(endDate, 'yyyyMMdd')")
    private Collection<Child> childCollection = new HashSet<Child>();
}
```

And make sure you enable the filter...

Comment: The @FilterDef annotation is accepted only on the class, but with this correction it works. I edited your answer with the correction, but "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.". Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Yes you are right it is not accepted on METHOD/FIELD.  But, just to be completely accurate, it is not limited to just TYPE (Class); you can also define it on PACKAGE.  Noticed you edit was rejected already by someone, I'll update it (I think I can my own...)

Comment: @SteveEbersole , Super Duper Thanks! I was stuck from last 2 days