# Filter child object in Spring Data Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a following domain model:

`Playlist` -> `List<PlaylistItem>` -> `Video`

```
@Entity
class Playlist{
   // id, name, etc
   List<PlaylistItem> playlistItems;
   // getters and setters
}


@Entity
class PlaylistItem{
   // id, name, etc.
   Video video;
   // getters and setters
}


@Entity
class Video{
   // id, name, etc.
   boolean isDeleted;
   // getters and setters
}
```

And my repository:

```
public interface PlaylistRepository extends JpaRepository<Playlist, Long> {
   List<Playlist> findAll();
}
```

Now, how do I return a playlist with only existing videos, ie, if there are three videos in the database assigned to that playlist item and one of those videos has isDeleted set to true, then I need to get only two items instead.

Comment: I guess you are asking about something similar to Hibernate FilterDef and Filter functionality. Unfortunately I don't know the easy way to use anything similar in spring data jpa. FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619174/hibernate-filter-children

Comment: All of the answers provided so far, are just about querying to get the PlayLists that have at least one non-deleted item, not to filter out the *delete items* once you get the lists back. @VadimKirilchuk is the only one with a solution that will change what items you are getting back.

Answer (score 23):

All you have to do is declare this method on your `PlaylistRepository` interface:

```
List<Playlist> findByPlaylistItemsVideoIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted);
```

And call it like this:

```
playListRepository.findByPlaylistItemsVideoIsDeleted(false);
```

That will return all playlist with videos that are not removed.

Comment: could you explain how this magically works? Any reference to jpa where this is described?

Comment: @judos Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 7):

You may have already resolved this issue, but I thought I would contribute this in hopes it might help you, or anyone else visiting this page.

Using Spring JPA Specifications, you would:

1. Enable your `PlaylistRepository` to use JPA Specifications
2. Write the `Specification` as a reusable method
3. Make use of the `Specification` as the query

Here are the details.

#### 1.  Implement `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

Update `PlaylistRepository` to implement `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.  This adds `find*` methods that accept `Specification<T>` parameters to your `PlaylistRepository`.

```
public interface PlaylistRepository extends JpaRepository<Playlist, Long>, 
            JpaSpecificationExecutor<Playlist> {

}
```

#### 2.  Create the `Specification`

Create a class with a static method for use in creating a *reusable* `Specification`.

```
public final class PlaylistSpecifications {

    private PlaylistSpecifications() {}

    public static Specification<Playlist> hasExistingVideos() {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            return cb.equal(root.join("playlistItems").join("video")
                    .get("isDeleted"), false);
        };
    }
}
```

Using `root.join` (and subsequent `join`s) is similar to using `JOIN` in SQL.  Here, we are joining on the *fields of classes*, instead of on columns of tables.

#### 3.  Issue the Query

I don't know how you plan to issue your query, but below is an example of how it could be done in a "service" class:

```
@Service
public class PlaylistService {

    @Autowired
    private PlaylistRepository playlistRepository;

    public List<Playlist> findPlaylistsWithExistingVideos() {

        Specification<Playlist> spec = PlaylistSpecifications.hasExistingVideos();
        return playlistRepository.findAll(spec);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Maksim, you could use the *@query* annotation like this :

```
public interface PlaylistRepository extends JpaRepository<Playlist, Long> {
   @Query("select playlist from Playlist playlist 
           fetch join playlist.playlistItems itens
           fetch join itens.video as video
           where video.isDeleted = false")
   List<Playlist> findAll();
}
```

Or even better way :

```
public interface PlaylistRepository extends JpaRepository<Playlist, Long> {
   @Query("select playlist from Playlist playlist 
           fetch join playlist.playlistItems itens
           fetch join itens.video as video
           where video.isDeleted = :hasVideo ")
   List<Playlist> findPlayList(@Param("hasVideo") boolean hasVideo);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look into Spring Data Specifications. You use them by calling repository.findAll(s);

Specifications allow you add on arbitrary conditions to your query, including the filter you want to add. Another nice thing about Specifications is that they can be type-safe. See here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: How would one structure a JPA Specification to query for `Playlist`s using `Video.isDeleted()`?  Would this involve using `Join<Z, X>`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work on the same project any more so I've fallen out of touch with the tech - hope someone else can help!