# Using referencing class field as filter in Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data

Context: I have three models, Owner, Property and Community. Property has a reference to its Owner, and another one to the Community.

I need to make the following query: find all the owners in a community which meet some criteria (floor number, property letter, etc, all the fields of the criteria are inside the Property class)

Is there any way to implement this in a repository without creating a bidirectional relationship or writing a native query? Something like:

```
Set<Owners> findAllByCommunityAndProperty_floorNumberAndProperty_letter(Community community, Property property);
```

(I would need a bidirectional relationship to make the query above)

Comment: You'll have to specify Property fields values separately, like

`Set<Owners> findAllByCommunityAndPropertyFloorNumberAndPropertyLetter(Community community, Integer floorNumber, Character letter);`

[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684361/filter-child-object-in-spring-data-query) question may be related.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this

```
SELECT o 
FROM Property p 
INNER JOIN property.owners o
WHERE p. ...
```

See http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#INNER_JOIN_ for various examples of join syntax.

In Spring Data JPA you will probably use the [`@Query` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) to bind that query to a method.