# Spring Data JPA: Query for Field in List of Objects

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I'm looking for the correct method name to find all `Document`s with a given `Target`'s `type`:

```
public class Document {

    @Indexed(name = "targets")
    private List<Target> targets;

    public class Target {
        private String value;
        private String type;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, all of the following method names aren't working:

```
List<Document> findByTargetType(...);
List<Document> findByTargetsTargetType(...);
List<Document> findByTargetsContainsTargetType(...);
List<Document> findByTargetsContainsTargetTargetType(...);
List<Document> findByTargetsContainingTargetType(...);
List<Document> findByTargetsContainingTargetTargetType(...);
```

So which is the correct method name to accomplish the desired feature?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684361/filter-child-object-in-spring-data-query

Comment: Is this about spring-data-jpa or spring-data-mongodb? Please remove the other tag.

Comment: @JensSchauder thank's for pointing that out. It's about the naming conventions we have to follow in order to avoid writing queries for JPA or Mongo-Repositories, so it applies to both. How would you suggest to tag it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below query.

Using `@Query` annotation

```
@Query("{ 'targets.type' : ?0 }")
List<Document> findByTargetsType(String type);
```

Or

Using repository supported keywords

```
List<Document> findByTargetsType(String type);
```

Comment: `findByTargetsType(String type)` is what I was looking it. Thank you.